# How to delete recovery mode

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode

Which files I need to delete from the system of a rooted device to delete completely the recovery mode, and in which folder I can find them?

Ty

Comment: block odin download mode
https://ge0n0sis.github.io/posts/2016/05/how-to-lock-the-samsung-download-mode-using-an-undocumented-feature-of-aboot happy bricking
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3775903